# Local host WordPress website URL changed not able to revert back

Tags: wordpress, url, localhost, web-hosting

I wanted to test my localhost WordPress website on a mobile device on my local network, So I changed my website URL and Site URL to http://192.168.1.3.8888 (wifi IP: Mamp apache port) previously it was http://localhost:8888/wordpress, Now I am unable to access the site from own pc with the new or the old URL.

I think in the new URL I used a '.' instead of a ': ' between the wifi IP and Port number can somebody help to revert the changes I have made or make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace or export data using [Wp Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/).
Easy to replace any url in your current database without lose any data or serialization issue.

[Changing the Site URL multiple ways.](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings)

**net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
Change your post 8888 to 80 in site & home url.
Its best to run of port 80 though instead of 8888.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I'm unable to access my wp-admin or even my website with the old URL or the new URL I have used. Can you please tell me how to revert back to old URL.

Comment: review my updated answer. try to change using config.php  option if not work then change in mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have changed URL using PhpMyAdmin but after changing it, the browser is giving the error message like This site can’t be reached - localhost refused to connect. My Mamp server is running then also it shows like this.

Comment: Check for mamp :https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP

Comment: The old URL is also not working, I have restarted the Mamp then also it shows like localhost refused to connect.

Comment: try to change post 8888 to 80 in site & home url.

Comment: I changed my Apache port to 80 and mSql to 3306, then the it shows an error like This page isn’t working
               localhost redirected you too many times.
                 Try clearing your cookies.
             ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I Cleared all the Cookies and even browsing history then also it shows the same error.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open phpmyadmin or another mysql db manager
2. Browse your website's wp_options table.
3. You will see 2 related rows there called "siteurl", and "home".
4. Fix them to correct address. 
   That's all.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have changed URL using PhpMyAdmin but after changing it, the browser is giving the error message like This site can’t be reached - localhost refused to connect. My Mamp server is running then also it shows like this.

Comment: This is webserver problem, related to IP network configuration of localhost. If you write old correct address via phpmyadmin, you will see that it becomes working.  
May be yo need to open Apache site conf file and add 192.168.1.3 there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried 80 port instead of 8888? May be this custom port is not allowed in your intranet network.